# Performing Hajj in behalf of someone who is old

Tags: halal-haram, hajj

I read that you can perform Hajj in behalf of someone only if he/she is old or suffering from a sickness from which there is no hope of recovery.

Source: https://islamqa.info/en/65641

My question is: How old does that person have to be? If he/she is over 50, does that count as old age? Would that mean I can perform hajj in behalf of that person? What is the minimum age someone has to be, such that he can send someone else to perform hajj for him?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a minimum age, it's rather related to capability : you can be a 60 years old healthy man or a 40 years old fragile person (who could suffer doing the Hadj)

So, it's more about someone being true to himself and knowing his capacity to accomplish the Hadj or not.